# Regex Pattern for Textfield

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex pattern for my textfield. I want it to accept letters, numbers as well as two special characters(underscore and hyphen). It can contain any number of words, and no other special characters are allowed except underscore and hyphen in between the words or starting/end of words. Space is also allowed between the words. But if a user will enter space/hyphen/underscore alone then it shouldn't accept.
i.e,

```
var a = "abc_def" //allowed
var b = "abc def" //allowed
var c = "abc-def" //allowed
var d = "abc*def" //not allowed, all other special characters are also not allowed
var e = " " // not allowed
var f = "_" // not allowed
var g = "-" // not allowed
```

I wrote below regex pattern

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9])+([\-|_])?)+$
```

but it's not accepting space if entered in between the words. It should accept as I wrote in above 7 scenarios. How can I rectify the issue?

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[-_ ][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gX4KU/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks for your time and quick help. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern is missing a space in the character class.

It will also match a trailing underscore or hyphen as the character class to match a char a-z or a digit followed by a special character is repeated as a whole using `)+` at the end.

You could first match `[A-Za-z0-9]+`, use a character class `[ _-]` to match any of the 3 allowed characters and repeat the non capturing group `(?:` one or more times.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dUrNwI/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a space in your square brackets:

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9])+([\-|_ ])?)+$
```

Run the code below to test.

```js
var a = "abc_def" //allowed
var b = "abc def" //allowed
var c = "abc-def" //allowed
var d = "abc*def" //not allowed, all other special characters are also not allowed
var e = " " // not allowed
var f = "_" // not allowed
var g = "-" // not allowed

var regex = /^(([A-Za-z0-9])+([\-|_ ])?)+$/;

console.log(regex.test(a));
console.log(regex.test(b));
console.log(regex.test(c));
console.log(regex.test(d));
console.log(regex.test(e));
console.log(regex.test(f));
console.log(regex.test(g));
```

Comment: Due to the optional pattern inside a `+` quantified group, `^(([A-Za-z0-9])+([\-|_ ])?)+$` will cause freezes often with non-matching strings.